# Why does the second clause of "Bob kicked the boy, injuring his left knee" use "injuring" instead of "injured"?

Tags: verbs, clauses, present-participles

> "Bob kicked the boy, injuring his left knee."

1. I don't understand why the clause uses present participle (injuring) instead of the past tense (injured) of the verb?
2. Does this sentence mean Bob hurts himself?

I have read [When it is appropriate to use "-ing" in a dependent clause?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299452/when-it-is-appropriate-to-use-ing-in-a-dependent-clause), but it didn't explain why the clause can use present participle.

Comment: Preliminary point: It's ambiguous as to whether it was Bob or the boy whose knee was injured. "Injuring" may be a present participle, but the clause that contains it is non-finite (tenseless), so it's the matrix clause verb that determines the time of the action. Here, the matrix verb "kicked" is past tense, so we know that the action occurred some time in the past. Btw, the subordinate clause is an adjunct -- it indicates a resultant or subsequent situation.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks in any way!

Comment: @fitz - Fitz thanked Bill, [thereby] acknowledging his contribution [by doing so].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to item #1, the usage of a present participle indicates that although the event occurred in the past, *kicked the boy*, the injury occurred concurrently with the event.  Another similar construct would be *He kicked the boy and injured his knee.*  The meanings of these two phrases are the same. You can swap them as you see fit.

In response to item #2, as BillJ notes in his comments, we cannot determine whose knee was injured.

UPDATE: I had a chance to think about this answer and realized it does not answer the **Why** of your question.  They mean the same thing but **why** would I use one over the other?  Do I just randomly pick one as I begin speaking?  No.  They mean the same thing but they are used in different situations.

In order to better illustrate the different situations, let's first use a sentence without the ambiguity of the original sentence, *Bob kicked the table, breaking its leg.*  This particular structure is a type of tense in the English language where I acknowledge a situation that happened in the past, *kicked the table*, but then describe the subsequent events in an active voice.  The simple past tense of *Kicked the table* lets you know every subsequent action happens in the past but I use *breaking* to give the situation *life*.  In this past event, as you picture it in your mind, I want you to think of the table leg *breaking* as if it is occurring as I tell you, as opposed to it being *broke* - an action that occurred in the past.  When and why would I want to do that?

If you asked me what happened at Bob's house last night I would most likely report to you, *Bob kicked a table and broke the table's leg.*  It's highly unlikely that I would report last night's events using the present participle *breaking*.  What if more things happened last night?  *Bob kicked a table, broke the table's leg, knocked a bowl of fruit on the floor, and scared the cat which tipped over a candle and caught the curtains on fire.*  That type of sentence is a very passive construct, best used for reporting events to someone.  It makes for a succinct summary of what happened last night, quite suitable for reporting those events to someone else.  Your *fiction writing* professor, however, is going to be quite unimpressed by that type of sentence.  It's dead and uninteresting.

In order to impress your fiction writing professor you need to breathe some life into that scene. *Bob kicked a table, breaking the table leg, knocking a bowl of fruit on the floor and scaring the cat so badly that it tipped over a candle catching the curtains on fire.*  Can you see the movement in that scene?  Things are alive.  Things are moving, breaking, knocking, and scaring.

Both constructs mean exactly the same thing.  I use the simple past to *report events to you*.  I use a mixture of simple past and preset participle to *tell you a story.*

Comment: Many thanks, I think your response to item #2 is right. But I'm not quite sure for item #1, if i have figured out it, I will accept your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you are figuring out but there is no need to report back to me when you do.  I didn't ask a question.

Comment: Good answer. Minor quibble: *"... starting the curtains on fire"* sounds wrong to me. Perhaps *"... and set the curtains on fire"* or *"... and set the curtains afire"*.

Comment: Thanks, this answer opened up my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

"injuring his left knee" is an adverbial phrase that modifies "kicked". It describes what happened with the main verb, so while it happened it the past relative to the present, it happened after the kicking happened, and thus the present progressive is used. Other examples of the present progressive being used to describe something with the main action are "She walked down the street, singing all the way" and "They poured the water carefully, avoiding any being spilled".

The past participle is used when describing an attribute that already existed at the time of the main action, such as "He stayed in bed as the phone rang, too tired to get up".